# cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' with an index of type 'String' self[key]

Tags: swift

I have Dictionary of type Dictionary (Key, Value). When I am trying to access the value it's giving the error:

> cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary' with an index of type 'String' self[key]

My Class.

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    public func optionalValue<T>(_ key: String) throws -> T?
    {
        guard let value = self[key],
            !(value is NSNull) else { return nil }
        guard let typedValue = value as? T else { throw JSONParserError.invalidValue(key: key, value: value) }

        return typedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following built from your question above compiles and works fine for me in a playground using Xcode 10.2.

```
import Foundation

extension Dictionary where Key == String {

    public func optionalValue<T>(_ key: String) throws -> T? {
        guard let value = self[key] else { return nil }
        guard !(value is NSNull) else { return nil }
        guard let typedValue = value as? T else { throw NSError() }
        return typedValue
    }

}

var dictionary = [String:Any]()
dictionary["nullKey"] = NSNull()
dictionary["intKey"] = 12345

var value: Int?
value = try dictionary.optionalValue("nullKey")
value = try dictionary.optionalValue("intKey")
```

The line `value = try dictionary.optionalValue("nullKey")` outputs `nil` as expected and `value = try dictionary.optionalValue("intKey")` outputs `12345`.

So to answer your question it should work fine.

Comment: I created a similar variant where all I changed from the OP's code was the type of thrown error (to `NSError()`, just as you did) and it compiled fine in Xcode 9.2. So it's  evidently impossible to reproduce any issue based on what the OP has said.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. Actually in my case the code was something like that

```
var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
```

So When It was getting Int value it was throwing Error.

This solved the issue.

```
var dictionary = [String:Any]()
```

Comment: The above shouldn't compile since you are attempting to shove an `Int` which is a structure into the dictionary however you have defined the dictionary as only accepting things that are classes. Yup you should see `Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'AnyObject?'` for line `dictionary["intKey"] = 12345`. So still not clear what the issue is, you helper should work just fine against AnyObject dictionaries assuming was you are trying to pull out is able to marshaled to the desired type otherwise you throw will fire of course.

Comment: Actually data was coming from Server ... Thats why it was compiling  successfully.. Now I edited my answer for any misconceptions